# How to change checkbox required message

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to change my checkbox required default message.

I am trying with this code but  if I check my checkbox then it still shows required message.

my code

```
<input  required type="checkbox" name="rcheck2" 
oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('check plz')" oninput="setCustomValidity('')" />
```

https://jsfiddle.net/6ekk9upz/

Comment: Please post a functional example that illustrates your problem on [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/).

Comment: Show us all the code. We are not able to help you when we don't see what you are doing ;) BTW Why are you calling JS "this." object in html as i see?

Comment: please check https://jsfiddle.net/6ekk9upz/ @palaѕн

Answer (score 15):

checkbox inputs don't have the `oninput` event, they have the `onchange` event.

Check this:

```html
<form action="" name="formReg" id="formReg" method="post" class="formReg">
  <div class="checkTxt">
    <input  required type="checkbox" name="rcheck1" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('check plz')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
  </div>
  <div class="checkTxt">
    <input  required type="checkbox" name="rcheck2" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('check plz')"  onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
  </div>
  <div class="checkTxt">
    <input  required type="checkbox" name="rcheck3" oninvalid="this.setCustomValidity('check plz')" onchange="this.setCustomValidity('')"/>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="btnReg" value="Submite"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

simply try this code , this is for typescript (react) but you can do as you like

```
          onInvalid={(e) => {
            const target = e.target as HTMLInputElement
            target.setCustomValidity("Please tick this box to proceed.")
          }}
```